# Submit form confirmation text present at the begining

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Have some problem with my "Your message has been submitted!" text after user click submit button on my form. Problem is this text is appearing at the begining even if nothing has been clicked yet, so when you go my page this text is already there... WHat is wrong here?

Form:

```
<form role="form" id="contactForm">
     <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Wpisz swoje imię, nazwisko" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="btn-block">Wyślij wiadomość</button>
 <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden">Your message has been submitted!</div>
     </div>
    </form>
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactForm").on("submit", function(event) {
        if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
            submitForm();
        }
    });

    $("#msgSubmit").removeClass("hidden");
});

function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: $("#contactForm").serialize(),
        success: function(text) {
             if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            }
        },
        error : function() {
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function formSuccess() {
    $("#msgSubmit" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
});

</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$EmailTo = "unknown@unknwon.com.pl";
$Subject = $name;

$message .= "\n\n" . 'From: '. $email;
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $message);

// redirect to success page
if ($success){
   echo "success";
}else{
    echo "invalid";
}
?>
```

Comment: you are removing the "hidden" class in onReady. And you are doing it twice. Why?

Comment: what then should i change, cna you propose an answer ?

Comment: As described in my answer, you need to show the message when the form has been submitted and hide it again at the end of the call.

Comment: actually... because you are saying that the form has been submitted. probably the message should be shown only on success. It depends on how much time it takes the ajax call. If it is fast, it is enough to write the message at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have:

1. moved the remove class in the submit event.
2. removed the "ready" handler at the end because I think that it was not necessary.
3. added a add class when the ajax call ends

Script (first option):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactForm").on("submit", function(event) {
        if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#msgSubmit").removeClass("hidden");
            submitForm();
        }
    });

});

function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: $("#contactForm").serialize(),
        success: function(text) {
            $("#msgSubmit" ).addClass( "hidden" );
        },
        error : function() {
                $("#msgSubmit" ).addClass( "hidden" );
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

Second option (message only at the end if success):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactForm").on("submit", function(event) {
        if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
            submitForm();
        }
    });

});

function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: $("#contactForm").serialize(),
        success: function(text) {
            if (text == "success") {
                $("#msgSubmit" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#msgSubmit" ).addClass( "hidden");    
                }, 3000);
            }
        },
        error : function() {
            /* You probably want to add an error message as well */
            $("#msgError" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: i choosed second option - but how to make message dissaper lets say after 4 seconds and all fields to be reset?

Comment: if you can please support on above

Comment: In the function of the timeout, add back the hidden class

Comment: can you update your second approach about this function then i will mark as answer

Comment: Marco you genious :) thanks - one more last question if dont mind - as my clients sometimes comes from Poland there are some special letters when they type are not correctly recognized on email boxes - do you know how to read such text as ę, ą, ż? Is there any option in outlook as i am using English one or maybe its somwhere in script i have to handle?

Comment: Somewhere, unfortunately the problem can be in many different places, you are not using the correct charset. Often it happens that the database has been created with a default charset that is not utf-8. If you want to be sure that any character will be correctly handled, you need to use utf-8 or at least you need to be consistent with the charset you use.

Comment: Hi @Marco Altieri  - could you be so kind and take a look on that topic - its related to this one in fact http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601027/javascript-markers-issue

Answer (score 0):

You are removing class `hidden` from `#msgSubmit` container in `document.ready`. You should enable this message only after form is successfully submitted.

Comment the line as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactForm").on("submit", function(event) {
        if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
            submitForm();
        }
    });

    //$("#msgSubmit").removeClass("hidden"); // comment this line
});
```

Comment: funny thing but i checked your solution and rest others posted here and still when going my page i see that message at the beginning...

Comment: Can you post css for class `hidden` ?

Comment: this is bootstrap framework class - Samir forget i already implemented  Marco's solution and yours as helpfull - thanks !!