# Javascript markers issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

On my page i have bootstrap owl carousel and contact form. Problem is either contact form is working or carousel slider sliding pictures - one from both. I found out where the problem is but have no idea how to solve that. Below find my JS code. First is for owl carousel and rest two for my contact form.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var owl = $("#owl-hero");

    owl.owlCarousel({

        navigation: false, // Show next and prev buttons
        slideSpeed: 1,
        paginationSpeed: 400,
        singleItem: true,
        transitionStyle: "fade"

    });
    });

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactForm").on("submit", function(event) {
        if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
            submitForm();
        }
    });

});

function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: $("#contactForm").serialize(),
        success: function(text) {
            if (text == "success") {
                $("#msgSubmit" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#msgSubmit" ).addClass( "hidden");    
                }, 6000);
            }
        },
        error : function() {
            /* You probably want to add an error message as well */
            $("#msgError" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
        }
    });
};

</script>
```

When i use as above - my contact form is working i mean mail i send and message is shown to user - but my carousel is not sliding pictures - it's stack.

If i want my carouse works i have to cut markers at the end like within below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var owl = $("#owl-hero");

    owl.owlCarousel({

        navigation: false, // Show next and prev buttons
        slideSpeed: 1,
        paginationSpeed: 400,
        singleItem: true,
        transitionStyle: "fade"

    });
```

this one was cutted from the end:

```
});
```

and now carousel works but not contact form. I belive i still have some marker typo within my JS, can you take a look?

**FURTHER DISCUSSION:**
If i split carousel JS to separate  bracket - but without correctly enclosed mark - then everything seems to be working.. ;/ see below:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var owl = $("#owl-hero");

    owl.owlCarousel({

        navigation: false, // Show next and prev buttons
        slideSpeed: 1,
        paginationSpeed: 400,
        singleItem: true,
        transitionStyle: "fade"

    });
    }
</script>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactForm").on("submit", function(event) {
        if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
            submitForm();
        }
    });

});

function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: $("#contactForm").serialize(),
        success: function(text) {
            if (text == "success") {
                $("#msgSubmit" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#msgSubmit" ).addClass( "hidden");    
                }, 6000);
            }
        },
        error : function() {
            /* You probably want to add an error message as well */
            $("#msgError" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
        }
    });
};

</script>
```

Comment: Have you encounter any JS error in browser console?

Comment: the only way to make it works is to separate carousel JS script in its own <script</script> brackets but without last: });

Comment: Answer added please try and see if it work or not.

Comment: does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var owl = $("#owl-hero");

    owl.owlCarousel({

        navigation: false, // Show next and prev buttons
        slideSpeed: 1,
        paginationSpeed: 400,
        singleItem: true,
        transitionStyle: "fade"

    });

    $("#contactForm").on("submit", function(event) {
        if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
            submitForm();
        }
    });

});

function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: $("#contactForm").serialize(),
        success: function(text) {
            if (text == "success") {
                $("#msgSubmit" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#msgSubmit" ).addClass( "hidden");    
                }, 6000);
            }
        },
        error : function() {
            /* You probably want to add an error message as well */
            $("#msgError" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: carousel not working -i mean no sliding... its stack on first picture

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the comment inside the json:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var owl = $("#owl-hero");

owl.owlCarousel({

    navigation: false,
    slideSpeed: 1,
    paginationSpeed: 400,
    singleItem: true,
    transitionStyle: "fade"

});
});
```

It is not syntactically correct.

Comment: did but still the same.

Comment: What browser are you using?  Firefox + Firebug is more reliable in case of errors. Chrome sometimes fails without saying why.

Comment: i am using chrome, firefox, ie, edge. What exactly can i do to report you and investigate that?